# XMLHTTPRequest read local file not working on all browsers

Tags: xmlhttprequest

```
<!DOCTYPE html> <html> <head> <script>
    function loadXMLDoc(url) {
        var xmlhttp;
        var txt, x, xx, i;
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        }
        else {// code for IE6, IE5
            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                txt = "<table border='1'><tr><th>Title</th><th>Artist</th></tr>";
                x = xmlhttp.responseXML.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("curriculum_item");
                for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
                    txt = txt + "<tr>";
                    xx = x[i].getElementsByTagName("title");
                    {
                        try {
                            txt = txt + "<td>" + xx[0].firstChild.nodeValue + "</td>";
                        }
                        catch (er) {
                            txt = txt + "<td> </td>";
                        }
                    }
                    xx = x[i].getElementsByTagName("abstract");
                    {
                        try {
                            txt = txt + "<td>" + xx[0].firstChild.nodeValue + "</td>";
                        }
                        catch (er) {
                            txt = txt + "<td> </td>";
                        }
                    }
                    txt = txt + "</tr>";
                }
                txt = txt + "</table>";
                document.getElementById('txtCDInfo').innerHTML = txt;
            }
        }
        xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    } </script> </head> <body>

<div id="txtCDInfo"> <button onclick="loadXMLDoc('curriculum_materials.xml')">Get CD info</button> </div>

</body> </html>
```

Hi all,

I need to create an html5 page where it reads from an file and shows content on html5 page. This is working fine when i run it on visual studio.

But when i copy these to some other folder and run from there it does not work on most of browsers. Tried it on IE 9, firefox and chrome.  I need to write this on CD so that it autoruns when i insert cd.  Please find code above. I know many have asked the same question but could not find solution for this.

Comment: Here there is no cross domain issue. The html5 page has to read local xml file and show output. This is a very simple application to read xml and display content. But to write it to cd i have copied bin folder, xml file and html page to different folder and tried to run html page from there. But not displaying content of xml. Please please help.

Comment: Changed code bit. Now it is working on Firefox perfectly. IE it is not working and in chrome if i run as chrome.exe --allow-file-access-from-files it works. I am using Windows 7. and please find code below. There should be solution so that it works on all browsers right? cant paste code because of char limit.

Answer (score 0):

This is answer for IE. I have it on Win 7 Pro, IE 11. I started where you are -same issue and worked it for IE.

```cs
xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
xmlhttp.open("GET", "myXMLfile.xml", false);
xmlhttp.send();
var parser = new DOMParser();
var xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(xmlhttp.responseText, 'text/xml');

// Now this works
alert(xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("Item")[0]);
```